# lidar_euclidean_cluster_detect frame is wrong

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone. I am using the lidar_euclidean_cluster_detect and I have noticed that the frame is wrong in the `/detection/objects` topic.

In the header I have what I put as output_frame as I expected but the position values are not TFed ! It's still in the same frame as the input (lidar).

Example here : https://imgur.com/a/DxeKvPG
The points are still in Lidar frame and not map frame, even if the header says so ! It really looks like a bug.

I just realized that the `convex_hull` is also wrong in the topic `cloud_clusters`.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/363415/lidar_euclidean_cluster_detect-frame-is-wrong/) by [Mackou](https://answers.ros.org/users/46580/mackou/) on ROS Answers with karma: 196 on 2020-10-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sgermanserrano](https://answers.ros.org/users/41059/sgermanserrano/) on 2020-10-15**:
@Mackou please feel free to open an issue in the repo and I'd encourage you to have a go at opening a PR to fix the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Confirmed bug.
My PR : https://gitlab.com/astuff/autoware.ai/core_perception/-/merge_requests/52

---

Originally posted by [Mackou](https://answers.ros.org/users/46580/mackou/) with karma: 196 on 2020-10-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [liyou zhou](https://answers.ros.org/users/47232/liyou-zhou/) on 2020-10-23**:
Hi Mackou, The main autoware development is happening on github https://github.com/Autoware-AI/core_perception. Would love to have your PR there. Today is the PR cut off date for 1.15 release if you submit your PR today, we can release this fix for 1.15.

**Comment by [Mackou](https://answers.ros.org/users/46580/mackou/) on 2020-10-23**:
Just did it : https://github.com/Autoware-AI/core_perception/pull/37
Thanks :)